# Render children of a wrapper component directly / Access component's children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I am using a [library](https://github.com/jeanverster/chakra-ui-steps/blob/be781613b7f232df6d43b225959080fbdeb65b8f/chakra-ui-steps/src/context/index.tsx#L25) that works to render a list of steps, like an onboarding screen.

```
<Parent>
   <Step1 />
   <Step2 />
   <Step3 />
</Parent>
```

However, I have code in which the state of specific steps are linked together. Thus I would prefer to structure my code like this:

```
<Parent>
   <Group1>
      <Step1 />
      <Step2 />
   </Group1>
   <Group2>
      <Step3 />
   </Group2>
</Parent>
```

Because the library uses the direct children of Parent (`{children}`), the library isn't working as intended even though I define my `Group1` component as a fragment:

```
const Group = () => {
  // shared state with useState
  const steps = [...]
  return <>{...steps}</>
}
```

Because the implementation of a group of steps is quite complex, I don't want to refactor all the state logic into the Parent component unless necessary.

Is there a way to

1. Keep the shared state between steps in a group
2. Render the steps as a flat list, OR access the children of each Group? E.g. render `Group.children`